# Ext JS 6 - DataView - ItemClick not attached

Tags: extjs

I've been unable to add an `itemclick` listener to what I thought was a very simple example. The view is shown correctly with the repeated HTML. Can anyone help with where I've gone wrong?

```js
Ext.define('App.view.Stuff', {
    extend: 'Ext.DataView',
    alias: 'view.stuff',
    store: [{
        "title": "Dataset 1",
        "desc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
    }, {
        "title": "Dataset 2",
        "desc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
    }],
    listeners: {
        itemclick: function () {
            console.log('itemclick');
        },
    },
    itemTpl:
      '<div><strong>{title}</strong></div>' +
      '<div>{desc}</div>'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since v6.5.0 the event is called [`childsingletap`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/Ext.dataview.DataView.html#event-childsingletap).

> **childsingletap ( this, location, eOpts )**
>        
>    Fires when a child is single tapped.
>
> `Available since: 6.5.0`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **this** :  `Ext.dataview.DataView`
>        
>    This dataview.
>
> **location** :  `Ext.dataview.Location`
>        
>    The location for the event.
>
> **eOpts** : `Object`
>        
>    The options object passed to Ext.util.Observable.addListener.

Here's the working code:

```js
Ext.define('App.view.Stuff', {
    extend: 'Ext.DataView',
    alias: 'view.stuff',
    store: [{
        "title": "Dataset 1",
        "desc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
    }, {
        "title": "Dataset 2",
        "desc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
    }],
    listeners: {
        childsingletap: function () {
            console.log('childsingletap');
        },
    },
    itemTpl:
      '<div><strong>{title}</strong></div>' +
      '<div>{desc}</div>'
});
```

Comment: Cheers, Martin :o)